# Setting default privileges on tables not working as expected in Postgres 13

Tags: postgresql

**Setup**: I'm using Google Cloud Platform's managed Postgres 13 instance, which is a fresh install with no existing tables or users (expect for the `postgres` admin).

**Goal**: I want to create a new database called `my_db` and have two new users `steve` and `mike` be able to execute DDL and DML commands on *future* tables (e.g., create new tables, insert data, read, etc). This also means `steve` and `mike` should be able to modify and read/write each other's tables.

**Problem**: Even when I create the users and set the `default privileges in schema public grant all` to tables in `my_db` only the creator (`steve`) of the new table can read/write the table while `mike` cannot. Furthermore, even the `postgres` admin cannot read the new table!

**Steps**: How to recreate

1. First I'll create the new database and users, plus give them lenient permissions to alter/read/write *future* tables in `my_db`.

```
-- Logged in as user = postgres (Connection 1)
\c postgres

create database my_db;

-- connect to my_db and create the new users
\c my_db

-- steve user
CREATE USER steve WITH PASSWORD 'pass123';
GRANT connect ON DATABASE my_db TO steve;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to steve;

-- mike user
CREATE USER mike WITH PASSWORD 'pass456';
GRANT connect ON DATABASE my_db TO mike;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to mike;
```

If my understanding is correct, `steve` and `mike` can now create and modify tables in `my_db`. Let's test this.

2. Then login as `steve` in a new connection #2 and create a new test table:

```
-- Logged in as user = steve (Connection 2)
\c my_db

create table test_tbl ( id int4 ); -- success
select * from test_tbl; -- 0 records
```

3. Now let's see if `mike` can read from the `test_tbl` which he *should* given the default privileges. We create connection #3 for `mike`:

```
-- Logged in as user = mike (Connection 3)
\c my_db

select * from test_tbl; -- ERROR: steve does not have permissions to read test_tbl!
```

This is my first point of confusion as I thought default permissions would let `mike` read the `test_tbl` created by `steve`.

1. As a final oddity I decided to circle back to the `postgres` user to test reading `test_tbl`:

```
-- Logged in as user = postgres (Connection 1)
\c my_db

select * from test_tbl; -- ERROR: steve does not have permissions to read test_tbl!

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, delete ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO mike; -- same error above!
```

So not even the admin user `postgres` can read this new table NOR can I grant permissions...

4. The only thing that worked is logging back in as `steve`--the original table creator--and granting `postgres` and `mike` permissions:

```
-- Logged in as user = steve (Connection 2)
\c my_db

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, delete ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO postgres; -- success
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, delete ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO mike; -- success
```

This all seems backwards. The `default privileges in schema public grant all` should take care of allowing users to modify future tables, right? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you actually changing the user. What does `select session_user, current_user;` show for each step?

Comment: Also in `psql` what does `\dp and \ddp` show for the tables?

Comment: You say you "circle back to postgres user", but you didn't show any commands that would have done that, and the error message clearly says you are still steve, not postgres.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I meant by lines like "-- user = steve" that I switched users using a completely different connection (in DBeaver).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` without the `FOR ROLE` clause affects only objects created by the role that ran the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement.

You would need two such statements to get what you want:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE mike GRANT ... TO steve;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE steve GRANT ... TO mike;
```

The other thing you want cannot be had in a straigtforward fashion. Only the owner (or members of that role) and superusers can `ALTER` or `DROP` an object. There is no way to grant that privilege. Your only solution would be to have a common `table_owner` role and have both users be a member of the role:

```
CREATE ROLE table_owner NOLOGIN;

GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema TO table_owner;

ALTER ROLE mike NOINHERIT;
ALTER ROLE steve NOINHERIT;

GRANT table_owner TO mike, steve;
```

Now both users need to `SET ROLE` to create a table in the schema:

```
SET ROLE table_owner;

CREATE TABLE myschema.atable (...);
```

That table is then owned by `table_owner`, and both users can `ALTER` or `DROP` it.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't fully understand the roles vs users nuance. I'll create the `table_owner` role and invite both `steve` and `mike` to that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The `NOINHERIT` prevents them from creating tables unless they run `SET ROLE`.